# Vulcan ship speed capability

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

What was the fastest a Vulcan ship could go during the 22nd century, since the enterprise could only go as fast as warp 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Suurok-Class vessel [Sh'Ran](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sh%27Raan) is noted to be able of reaching warp 7. Given that it's a relatively new vessel and intended for combat, I think it's reasonable to assume that it represents the cutting edge as far as engine design is concerned.

> **ARCHER:** *What if we could get a message through? Tell them to get here as fast as they can.*
>
> **T'POL:** ***The Sh'Raan is capable of warp seven.** If we could maintain warp five we'd reach them in twelve minutes.*
>
> <sub><sup>[ENT: Fallen Hero](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/23.htm)</sup></sub>

Historically, we've seen ships exceed their stated max-warp parameters by around 5-10%, suggesting that the Sh'Ran's absolute tippy-top speed is around warp 7.5 before it shakes itself apart.

[image]

Comment: A Vulcan ship meant for combat? Another reason to avoid the horrific rewriting of history that is Enterprise

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack - During this period Vulcan was facing a number of threats from their near neighbours. Building a vessel intended for combat seems eminently logical.

Comment: I refuse to accept Enterprise happened. It's all a dream.

Comment: @AncalagonTheBlack -  You aren't the [only person to think that](http://www.startrek.com/article/these-are-the-voyages-nine-years-later)